# Multiprocess pandas pd.read_sas

Tags: python, pandas, sas, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have an extremely large dataset from SAS and want to load it into Python using multiprocessing (if possible). My current code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool

sas_file = pd.read_sas('path',
                       encoding='ISO-8859-1',
                       chunksize=100000,
                       iterator=True)


def process_sas(chunk):
    dfs.append(chunk)


if __name__ == '__name__':
    pool=Pool()
    pool.map(process_sas, sas_file)
```

However, dfs is not defined using this method. Is there any way to multiprocess the SAS data set? Separating the data into chunks is not a requirement.

Thanks,

Comment: reading from a file with multiple threads will likely reduce the speed overall. You may have multiple cores, but that file only exists on one storage device. You probably already saturate the read speed with a single core, and concurrent reads will just compete with each other, and incur switching delay.

Comment: There's another problem here too... separate processes don't share memory with each other (for the most part), so modifying `dfs` in one process won't modify it in the others. Multiprocessing is good for when you have a CPU intensive task, not so much for I/O intensive tasks because there's a significant penalty to transferring large amounts of data between processes (and it has to be transferred because it is explicitly not shared).

Comment: Where do you have dfs defined in your program?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you defined dfs
Quick fix but not ideal: put dfs within the global scope
and then declare `global dfs` inside the respective function and/or method.

```
def process_sas(chunk):
    global dfs
    dfs.append(chunk)
```